# How can I put a draggable element who uses more than one droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I'm doing an agenda for appointments, my first question was how to accept just one draggable into a dropable and it was successfuly answered. Now my problem is that, for example, I want to make an appointment at 7:00 am and I want to make it bigger (Every droppable space is the equivalent of 15 minutes, so, 1 hour will be 4 droppables). In my case, one draggable is 15 minutes "size" minimum. There's some plugins but I'm new in Javascript and jQuery and I unforntunately don't understand too much.

Other big issue is that I manually assign the div's height for now, just for testing and later they'll be resizable. So, when I drag the item, it drops in the middle, not in the top, so I need to drag the item until the half of itself touches the desired droppable.

The items are divs whit a class, I'm using a table and every "td" is droppable.

I hope there's an answer for my question, thank you!

UPDATE:

The code is:

```
$( '.draggable_hour_1' ).resizable().draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone",
                    revert:'invalid'
            });
```

I have a validation on the droppable for not adding more than one draggable per droppable.

Comment: can you show the code you have worked on or tried?

Comment: Actually, I'm in zero ): what can I show you? here is a picture maybe is useful...

http://vegatech.mx/ProyectoPW/js.png